# How to split a string without touching some chars in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

So I have this string:
'm(1,2),m(4,3)'

How can I split it to get list that contains only 2 elements:
['m(1,2)', 'm(4,3)']

I can't use str.split function because it will split the whole string and would give me something like this:
['m(1', '2)', 'm(4', '3)']
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try regex:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("m\([0-9],[0-9]\)")
s = "m(1,2),m(4,3)"
regex.findall(s)
```

should yield:

```
['m(1,2)', 'm(4,3)']
```

Comment: btw if we had string like this:
'm(M(1,2),3),m(4,3)'
How to get list ['m(M(1,2),3)', 'm(4,3)']